# How can I extract a dynamic number from a webpage content with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

To give an example of what I'm trying to do, let's say there is a website that displays results of a lottery every hour. The webpage itself is static with the surrounding text staying the same and only the numbers changing (input by human not updated dynamically).

Something like `The lucky number is: X` where X indicates a different number each hour.

Now I want to run a python script that parses the number(s) each hour, and then at the end of the day would print out all the numbers in a nice format.

I know how to get the webpage content and get only the text parts of it without html tags etc by using the BeautifulSoup and requests libraries, however I'm not quite sure how to get the target number.

I was thinking something like a regex which would find a static word from the text e.g. 'number is:' in this case and then grab the word (number) right after it.

Is this doable? and if yes, how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with regex but if you know the string already and if it's static , use simple split on that string.
Let's say
var='The lucky number is: 123'
Out= int(var.split(':')[1])

Out will be 123

Comment: This would work if the webpage content ended at 123. But in my case there is more content afterwards which I don't want. By trying what you said I get the number I want as well as all the rest of the text found in the webpage that comes after the number.

Comment: I found a workaround, by doing two splits one for preceding text and one for the text after and although it does work, I'd like something less messier..

Comment: Can you try below , it will work if that is the first number in string-> re.search(r'\d+', var).group(0))